# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, orm, annotations

I'm trying to solve a problem with two datasources. I read many text in the internet and made simple solution based on [this source](https://github.com/gratiartis/multids-demo)

I've made two "config classes", like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "ResultEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "ResultEntityTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.migr.result.repositories"
        )
public class ResultTablesConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("orclAdapter")
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean(name="ResultEntityDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.migr.result")
     public DataSource declReaconDS() {
        return new DataSource();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ResultEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ResultEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(declReaconDS());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.migr.result.tables.*");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("ResultEntityPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ResultEntityTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
}
```

and another one, practically same - `SourceTablesConfig`.
only difference is `@Bean` names (they all start with "Source") and repositories mapping, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "SourceEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "SourceEntityTransactionManager",
                basePackages = "com.migr.source.repositories"
            )

public class SourceTablesConfig {
...............
@Bean(name = "SourceEntityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     lef.setDataSource(declReaconDS());
     lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
     lef.setPackagesToScan("com.migr.source.tables.*");
     lef.setPersistenceUnitName("SourceEntityPersistenceUnit");
     lef.afterPropertiesSet();
     return lef.getObject();
}
```

My services are simle:

```
@Service
public class CatalogsSourceService {
@Autowired
CatalogsSourceRepository catalogsrepository;
 .......
 }
```

where `CatalogsSourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Catalogs, Long>`

My "main" class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Main {

@Autowired
CatalogsSourceService source_serv;

@Autowired
CatalogsResultService result_serv;
 @RequestMapping
public Object index() {
    Map<String,List> results = new HashMap<>();
    results.put("First", source_serv.findAll());
    results.put("Second", source_serv.findAll());
    return results;
}
```

it worked perfectly when I was having only one DataSource,
but now it exits with error:
`expected single matching bean but found 2: SourceEntityManagerFactory,ResultEntityManagerFactory`

I don't get why it is happening. My solution looks practically like mentioned in above link, but his do not get such error.

I will be very gratefull for any help

PS. forgot about my "AppConfig":

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.migr" })
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="orclAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new     HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);        
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my problem is solved. I missed easiest solution).
I just had to annotate one `EntityManagerFactory` bean with `@Primary` annotation.

```
@Bean(name = "SourceEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
...........
}
```

obvious solutions are not always so obvious...